# How to find how many powers double 'n' is raised to to get to double 'n' in Java. Equivalent of Math.log in Python

Tags: java, python, math

I want to find the equivalent of `Math.log` in Python in Java. Basically how many powers is a `double 'n'` raised to to get to the full `double 'n'`. Example `(100, 10)` returns 2. Because, 10 is raised to the second power to get to 100.
`27, 3` returns: 3.
`49, 7` returns 2. Etc... 
Does anyone know what this would be in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python you can use [`math.log`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log) which takes a second argument which is the base.

```
>>> math.log(100, 10)
2.0
>>> math.log(27, 3)
3.0
```

In `Java` there is no such function, but you can trivially solve for the same thing

```
public double logOfBase(int base, int num) {
    return Math.log(num) / Math.log(base);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! :D

Comment: @ElginBeloy Google would've told you the answer immediately.

Comment: No It gives me how to raise a number to a certain power.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=math.log&oq=math.log&aqs=chrome..69i57.1238j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=+math.log+java

Comment: Java says it takes one argument. Are you sure this is not python?

Comment: @ElginBeloy The second argument is optional, you can [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log). If you do not pass it, the default base is `e`. If your question is about how to do this in `Java`, see my edit.